# Instagram Authorization Page Redirect is Endlessly Reloading My Web Page

Tags: php, wordpress, instagram

So I have the following method from the Instagram Basic Display API:

```
public function get_authorization_window(): string
    {
        $auth_url = $this->instagram->get_api_oauth_url() . '?' . http_build_query([
            'client_id' => $this->instagram->get_client_id(),
            'redirect_uri' => admin_url('options-general.php?page=instagram_auth'),
            'scope' => 'user_profile,user_media',
            'response_type' => 'code',
            'state' => admin_url('options-general.php?page=instagram_auth'),
        ]);

        return '<a class="button button-primary" href="' . $auth_url . '">Please click here to authorize Instagram for this site</a></p>';
    }
```

Now, when it builds the URL, it returns a `code=dsgzdfsgzsfsbfb` parameter.

**Here is the URL that I get in return**: `https://test.com.local/wp-admin/options-general.php?code=fsdgsfgfbxf`.

**Here is where I would like to be redirected**:  `https://test.com.local/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=instagram_auth&code=fsdgsfgfbxf`.

The following param need to get added: `page=instagram_auth&`.

I tried using this piece of code, but I am stuck in a redirect loop:

```
if (!empty($_GET['code'])) {
     $this->instagram->set_code($_GET['code']);
     header('Location:' . $config['redirect_uri'] . '&code=' . $_GET['code']);
     die();
}
```

Does anyone know how I can call a redirect but redirect just once and maybe build a link based on the code param?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here is the URL that I get in return:
>
> https://test.com.local/wp-admin/options-general.php?code=fsdgsfgfbxf.
>
> Here is where I would like to be redirected:
>
> https://test.com.local/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=instagram_auth&code=fsdgsfgfbxf.

The order doesn't really matter.  If you only have the first string, the following URL should be just as sufficient:

> https://test.com.local/wp-admin/options-general.php?code=fsdgsfgfbxf&page=instagram_auth

Notice, I just add the param on at the end.  This only requires that you append the `&page=instagram_auth` param to the string you already have.

The page should work the same, no matter what order the `GET` params are in.

It's difficult to say what exactly is going on, but maybe try?

```
if (!empty($_GET['code']) && $_GET['done'] != "1")) {
     $this->instagram->set_code($_GET['code']);
     header('Location:' . $config['redirect_uri'] . '&done=1&code=' . $_GET['code']);
     die();
}
```

Comment: This is good to know! I didn't know this, is there still a safe way to redirect the URL to the &page=instagram_auth param? Instagram strips all query strings and I need this added at the end, but I get stuck in a redirect loop since `code=vdvzsvs` stays in the url.

Comment: @Glider: Hrm, I'm not 100% clear about your problem.  But you want it to redirect once, and then not redirect anymore?  Does this work?  Change `header('Location:' . $config['redirect_uri'] . '&code=' . $_GET['code']);` to `header('Location:' . $config['redirect_uri']);`?

Comment: I just added some code that *might* solve your problem, let me know if it works!